# In $u^{T}A^{-1}= v^{T}B$ with $B$ being a non-square matrix, why are there infinite solutions for $v$?

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

I have a matrix equation in the form of

$$u^{T}A^{-1}=v^{T}B$$

where $u$ and $v$ are vectors, $A$ is a square matrix, and $B$ is a non-square matrix.

I'm told that while there is a unique solution for $u$ for a given $v$, $v$ has an infinite number of solutions for a given $u$.

Also, the general solution for $v$ is given as

$$v=B^{T+}A^{-T}u+(I-B^{T+}B^{T})w$$

1. Why does $v$ have an infinite number of solutions for a given $u$? Does it have to do with $B$ being non-square and having only a pseudoinverse?
2. Where is the term $(I-B^{T+}B^{T})w$ in the general solution for $v$ coming from?

Comment: To answer part 1, if $B$ has more rows than columns, then $B^T$ has a nontrivial null space, hence there are nonzero vectors $x$ satisfying $B^T x = 0$, or equivalently, $x^T B = 0$. f $v$ is a solution to the equation and $x^TB = 0$, then $v+x$ is also a solution to the equation. And the same is true for any scalar multiple of $x$, so that's why there are infinitely many solutions if there are more than one.

Comment: So would that mean that v would have a unique solution if B actually had more columns than rows?

Comment: Not necessarily. Suppose $u = 0$ and $B = 0$. Then $v$ can be anything, regardless of the dimensions of $B$.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the matrix $X\in{\mathbb C}^{m\times n},$ use its pseudoinverse to construct ortho-projectors into the nullspace 
$$P=I-X^+X\\Q=I-XX^+$$ 
The defining (and easily verified) properties of these projectors are
$$\eqalign{
 XP &= 0,\quad P^2=P=P^* \\
 QX &= 0,\quad Q^2=Q=Q^* \\
}$$
Set $\,X=B^T$ and check the proposed solution
$$\eqalign{
v &= \quad X^+A^{-T}u   &+\; Pw \\
Xv &= XX^+A^{-T}u &+\; 0 \\
}$$
This satisfies the original matrix equation only if  $\;XX^+=I_m$ 

In other words if $\;\operatorname{rank}(X) = m$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. My understanding in linear algebra is still lacking, so I have a couple of questions. Which null space are you referring to in the first sentence? For checking the solution, you only used $P$, which makes sense. In what case would $Q$ be used?

Comment: The $Q$ projector would be needed if the original equation had used $B^T$ instead of $B,\,$ i.e. $\,u^TA^{-1} = v^TB^T$. So one matrix projects into the nullspace of $B$, while the other projects into the nullspace of $B^T$.

Comment: makes sense, thank you